# Set environmenti variable to apache user

Tags: apache, variables

I would like to remove the password from mysql db code of my application and insert it into the server, i would not be seen by users of the shell. I thought to put it as environment variable of apache user (user running the php code) is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [PassEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) directive to pass OS environment variables to CGI scripts.

In PHP you can use [`$_ENV`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) to get the value of required variables.

Comment: How can i set the environment variable? If i insert into /etc/sysconfig/httpd, some user can view the password....

Comment: @hellb0y77 You can edit `.profile' or `.bash_profile` of the apache user (usually this user is named `apache` also) to set necessary environment variables. Other users can't read this file.

Comment: But apache user not have an home directory

Comment: @hellb0y77 Then check permissions of `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`. As I understand, they should be 0700 to deny the other users to read this file.

Comment: mmm..if i set 700, apache user cannot read this file, i suppose

Comment: @hellb0y77 Is `root` the owner of the file? If the `httpd` is not started, you can try `chown` for this file.